# Weird cookies in website

Tags: php, cookies

When I check `$_COOKIE` array in php, I see my cookies but a minority of users have weird cookies. For example they have these cookie keys. Each of them is a different cookie:

lbx1520m03d17n, ctxjs1420m06d05nn, 3e1dd89fdfa706ed2e69a8eccf98cab048d7b661_session

Doesn't `$_COOKIE` gives the cookies that we set ? Is it possible to reach other domain's cookies ? Because we don't set these three cookies. Their size is nearly 1k bytes.

What could be the reason to have an unknown cookie ? Can I safely delete this cookie from the users that has on their browser ?

Comment: Could be badly written browser extensions/user scripts. I don't think deleting them is a good idea... they don't harm you, do they?

Comment: Yes they dont harm. But I'm curious about the cause and also it increases request headers size of each request.

Answer (score 0):

$_COOKIE will give you all cookies and you can not access other domain's cookies. those are cookies set by session and deleting them wont make any harm.